Pandas time series group by time interval in seaborn box plot
I am trying to make a box plot that is grouped in half hour intervals on the x axis in seaborn. The data already looks like this:
index | X | Y | Z 
2024-04-03 10:10:10 | .1 | .2 | .3
2024-04-03 10:10:14 ...
...

and I want each box to group the data from column X in half hour buckets and column Y in a different colored box.
I have tried:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,8))
sns.boxplot(data=df, x=df.index, y=df["X"], orient="v", ax=ax)

and that comes up blank and I have tried the groupby:
df.groupby(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")).boxplot(subplots=False, figsize=(20,8), rot=90)

but I think I am missing some arguments or something.

Please provide a complete [mre], without ...

If I understood well your question, here is how you can overcome this problem :
Creating fake data (for example purpose, 10000 rows separated by 4 seconds) :
# Create a datetime index
index = pd.date_range(start='2024-04-03 10:10:10', periods=10000, freq='4s')

# Create random data for columns X, Y, and Z
data = np.random.rand(10000, 3)

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])

Now you can use this to have a boxplot for each 30 min interval (blue for column X and red for Y) :
# Create the box plot using Seaborn for column X
sns.boxplot(data=df, x=df.index.floor('30Min'), y='X')

# Create the box plot using Seaborn for column Y with a different color
sns.boxplot(data=df, x=df.index.floor('30Min'), y='Y', color='red')

# Rotate the x-axis labels for better visibility
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

# Add x-label
plt.xlabel('Time')

# Give a title to the plot and x-axis
plt.title("Boxplot of X and Y")

# Add some padding to the plot
plt.tight_layout()

# Show the plot
plt.show()

Result :

You may handle some aesthetic parameters like opacity for better visibility, or maybe your real data will make it clearer (because mine are random)

thank you, the index.floor is exactly what I was looking for!
I also had a xlim argument using pd.timestamps that was making it only generate a blank plot, but removing the argument has fixed it!
